How to handle session life cycle implicitly in FastAPI application?
I developed some wrappers for SQLAlchemy session for using in repositories in FastAPI application to ensure that there is only one single session per request. The final goal for this is to incapsulate working with session in autocommit mode (like for example in Django). The whole code is in my GitHub repository.
Work with database incapsulated in Database class:
import functools
from contextvars import ContextVar
from functools import wraps

from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, AsyncEngine, AsyncTransaction, AsyncConnection

session_context = ContextVar("session")


class SessionNotInitializedError(Exception):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Init session with init_session method")


class Session:

    def __init__(self, bind: AsyncEngine | AsyncConnection):
        self.bind = bind
        self.token = None

    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.session = AsyncSession(bind=self.bind, expire_on_commit=False)
        self.token = session_context.set(self.session)
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type=None, exc_value=None, traceback=None):
        await self.session.close()
        session_context.reset(self.token)

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            async with self:
                return await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper


class Transaction:

    def __init__(self, engine: AsyncEngine):
        self.engine = engine
        self.session = None

    async def __aenter__(self):
        connection = await self.engine.connect()
        self.transaction = await connection.begin()
        self.session = Session(bind=connection)
        await self.session.__aenter__()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type=None, exc_value=None, traceback=None) -> None:
        if exc_type is None:
            await self.commit()
        else:
            await self.rollback()
        await self.session.__aexit__()

    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            async with self:
                return await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper  # type: ignore

    async def commit(self):
        await self.transaction.commit()

    async def rollback(self):
        await self.transaction.rollback()


class Database:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.engine = create_async_engine(url, echo=True)

    def init_session(self):
        return Session(self.engine.execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT"))

    @property
    def __session(self) -> AsyncSession:
        try:
            return session_context.get()
        except LookupError:
            raise SessionNotInitializedError

    def transaction(self):
        return Transaction(self.engine)

    async def scalar(self, statement):
        return await self.__session.scalar(statement)

    async def scalars(self, statement):
        return await self.__session.scalars(statement)

    async def execute(self, statement):
        return await self.__session.execute(statement)

    async def get_by_pk(self, entity, ident, **kwargs):
        return await self.__session.get(entity, ident, **kwargs)

Create some instance of Database:
default_db = Database("postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost:5433/postgres")

Examples of use:
app = FastAPI()


@router.get("/user/{user_id}", response_model=UserSchema)
@default_db.init_session()
async def get_user(user_id: int, repo: UsersRepository = Depends()):
    return await repo.get_by_pk(user_id)

As you could see there is @default_db.init_session() call. This is explicit way.
But how could I init session implicitly? Well I guess it is not to much difficult to init session - session could be initialized at the first query method call. But how could I close it also implicitly? I mean how to catch finish of API view? In Session wrapper it is done in aexit method.
Maybe some way besides middleware?
The case above is case in web framework context. There is also another case for example somewhere else like in faststream tasks or in background tasks. F.e.
tasks.py


@default_db.init_session()
async def update_users_backgound_task():
    repo = UsersRepository()
    # doing something...
    


Any dependency can clean up after itself by yielding a session; given that the result from a dependency function is cached, you should be able to retrieve the current active session by having your dependency functions that return a repository depend on the get current session function. You'd have your session init as a root dependency on the app or apirouter. But if your goal is to replicate commit on successful response, a middleware seems more logical and where you'd expect it to live (and the session would be attached to the state of the request).

I also need it in besides fastapi context where dependencies are not available. f.e. in background (celery tasks f.e.)

Since the dependency functions are just plain functions, you can just call them manually. But use a middleware - write a context manager and use it in the middleware, and reuse it in your external functions.
